# Webbrowser LoadCompleted Event in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, webbrowser-control

First of all my declared variables in my Page1 Control:

```
private PPt.Presentation oPPPresentation = null;
    private PPt.Application oPPApplication = null;
    private PPt.SlideShowWindow oPPslideShow;
    private PPt.Slide oPPSlide;
    private Object oDocument;
```

I have currently a webBrowser control (called powerPointBrowser1) which displays a powerpoint passed by a string:

```
public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        powerPointBrowser1.Navigate(strFileName);
        powerPointBrowser1.LoadCompleted += powerPointBrowser1_LoadCompleted;
    }
```

This is my powerPoint1Browser_LoadCompleted method:

```
private void powerPointBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        oDocument = powerPointBrowser1.Document;
        oPPPresentation = (PPt.Presentation)oDocument;
        oPPApplication = oPPPresentation.Application;
    }
```

Now to my question: How can I get the LoadCompleted Method in my Page1ViewModel so I can have access to the oDocument in my VM?

Edit:

in my Page1.xaml.cs:

```
 public static DependencyProperty DocProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Doc"
        , typeof(Object)
        , typeof(Page1)
        , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null)
        { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true });
    public static Object GetDoc(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Object)obj.GetValue(DocProperty);
    }
    public static void SetDoc(DependencyObject obj, Object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(DocProperty, value);
```

and

```
private void powerPointBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        oDocument = powerPointBrowser1.Document;
        this.SetCurrentValue(DocProperty, oDocument); //new
        oPPPresentation = (PPt.Presentation)oDocument;
        oPPApplication = oPPPresentation.Application;
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
    public Object someVMProperty { get; set; }`
private string GetSlideNumber()

    {
        oPPPresentation = (PPt.Presentation)someVMProperty;`
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a dependency property to your window then you can bind that to a full  property in the viewmodel. Make that twoway using the meta setting on your dp.
Use setcurrentvalue on that dp to set it to your document and it will transfer to the viewmodel.
The setter on the viewmodel will fire and you can act in there to do whatever you want to do - call a method or whatever.

Having said that.
A web page is a view sort of an object and copying that to a viewmodel is usually considered something to be avoided. Maybe you should do some processing in the view and pass the result to the viewmodel.
MVVM doesn't always mean absolutely no code in the view.

Add a dependency property to a window. Use an attached property so we can set a binding in XAML in the window tag.
In the window

```
    public static DependencyProperty DocProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Doc"
            , typeof(HTMLDocument)
            , typeof(MainWindow)
            , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null)
        { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true });
    public static HTMLDocument GetDoc(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (HTMLDocument)obj.GetValue(DocProperty);
    }
    public static void SetDoc(DependencyObject obj, HTMLDocument value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(DocProperty, value);
    }
```

Obviously, your window may not be mainwindow and I'm not entirely sure what your doctype will be. This might need a bit of modification.

Build. Then you can stick in your window tag:

```
 local:MainWindow.Doc="{Binding someVMProperty}"
```

Here, someVMProperty is the property in your viewmodel which will get the document. That must be a public property with a get and set. You will call some method from the set. local is an xmlns reference to your project.

All you need to do is set that in your code you have.

```
this.SetCurrentValue(DocProperty, newValue);
```

Comment: oh, okay ill try that. Im very new into WPF and MVVM but thank you!
cant upvote- sorry.

Comment: No problem.  I could have posted code for a dp, how you bind it and then showed you code calling a method in a vm. I didn't do that because I'm not so sure that's really the way you ought to be doing whatever you intend doing. If I give you code to paste in, then your team lead sees it and says "wtf is this manipulating view objects in your viewmodel?".

Comment: okay, i gave up. i have no clue how to do it. how do i bind it?

Comment: I added some code to my post. Should at least get you headed in a useful direction.

Comment: hey andy, i added some code in my question. i dont know why it still wont work (i think because of the get/set of someVMProperty) but i dont know how to fix it. any suggestions? :/

Comment: SomeVMProperty probably ought to have a better more meaningful name. I'd make it a propfull with a full get and set. You can then put some code calls a method in the set and that drives your processing of the document. Also, put a break point in loadcompleted, step through and check you got the types right etc.

Comment: hmm yea that was my question :D i dont know how to select the object (oDocument) of my Page1 in my set method of someVMProperty

Comment: It's literally the value in your setter. In a propfull you have a full get and setter.  The setter looks roughly like set { whatever = value.  value being the value transferred from the bound property in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Not true MVVM but you could do it just by referencing directly in your main window, assuming you have Page1 (user control) + MainWindow:

```
public partial class Page1 : UserControl
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        powerPointBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.bbc.co.uk");
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Page1Model _pageModel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _pageModel = new Page1Model();
        DataContext = _pageModel;

        ctlPage1.powerPointBrowser1.LoadCompleted += _pageModel.BrowserLoadCompleted;
    }
```

Then you can handle that event inside your view model class:

```
public void BrowserLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
```

Page1 XAML contains the browser:

```
 <WebBrowser Name="powerPointBrowser1"/>
```

Main window contains the control:

```
 <local:Page1 Name="ctlPage1"/>
```

Comment: yea Page1 is an user control, but i need the Load Completed method in my VM (not in the MainWindow) because i need to work with the current Document (oDocument) in my other methods

Comment: How is the ViewModel created and does your main window have a reference to it in code?  Or just in XAML?

Comment: simple new class element if you mean that: in MainWindow.xaml.cs i got only DataContext = new Page1Model() in a btn click method
and in MainWindow.xaml: simple DataType & DataContext Binding

Comment: So when you create the Page1Model in your main window class, just set a class-level reference to it - then you can route a handler for ctlPage1.powerPointBrowser1.LoadCompleted to a function there.

Comment: @Adri1511 I've added it to the answer

Comment: wow, thanks but i cant name the Page1 (Page 1 implemented in the same Assembly it says) how do i fix this

Comment: Not sure what you're asking to fix.  Post a screenshot or something clear.

Comment: yeah i did, but x:Name is only known inside the XAML